# Simple probability question

Tags: probability, self-learning

**Question:**

In class of 125 students, in examination 70 students passed in mathematics and 55 students passed in statistics and 30 passed in both the subject.

Find the probability of the event where selected student has passed only in one subject.

**My Efforts:**

$P(M\ \cup\ S) = P(M) + P(B)- P(M\ \cap\ S) $

$P(M\ \cup\ S) = 70 + 55 - 30 = 95 $

So answer is $\frac{95}{125}= \frac{19}{25}=0.76$

But answer given is $\frac{13}{25}= 0.52$

I know i am missing something, but can't figure out what?

Comment: What is P(M)???

Comment: First of all, be careful. What you wrote above is not probability, it needs to be divided by 125 to become a probability. Second, did 70 or 50 students passed in Maths? Third, what you have supposedly found is the probability that a student passed in either subject. They are asking for the probability it passed in -one- subject only.

Comment: So what do you have to further decrease?

Comment: $P(M)\neq 70$ !!!

Comment: @Studentmath Ok i got. thanks for clue. It is easy with venn diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called the symmetric difference. Namely, $$A \triangle B = (A\cup B) - (A\cap B).$$

It's the union without the intersection.  If the left circle represents those passing math, and the right circle represents those passing stats, and we don't want those who passed both, we want to find the probability of the symmetric difference of the two.

You already found $P(M \cup S)$. Now you just need to subtract the probability of the intersection of the two.